# Python Hypothesis mixing strategies behavior for DataFrames

Tags: python-hypothesis

The following works as expected

```py
from datetime import datetime

from hypothesis.extra.pandas import columns, data_frames, indexes
import hypothesis.strategies as st


def boundarize(d: datetime):
    return d.replace(minute=15 * (d.minute // 15), second=0, microsecond=0)


min_date = datetime(2022, 4, 1, 22, 22, 22)
max_date = datetime(2022, 5, 1, 22, 22, 22)

dfs = data_frames(
    index=indexes(
        elements=st.datetimes(min_value=min_date, max_value=max_date).map(boundarize),
        min_size=3,
        max_size=5,
    ).map(lambda idx: idx.sort_values()),
    columns=columns("A B C".split(), dtype=int),
)
dfs.example()
```

with an output similar to

```
                              A           B           C
2022-04-06 12:45:00      -11482  1588438979 -1994987295
2022-04-08 15:45:00  -833447611           3         -51
2022-04-24 06:15:00  -465371373   990274387      -14969
2022-05-01 01:15:00  1750446827  1214440777         116
2022-05-01 06:15:00      -44089       30508       58737
```

now when I try to generate a similar DataFrame with evenly spaced DatetimeIndex values via

```py
from datetime import datetime

from hypothesis.extra.pandas import columns, data_frames, indexes
import hypothesis.strategies as st


def boundarize(d: datetime):
    return d.replace(minute=15 * (d.minute // 15), second=0, microsecond=0)


min_date_start = datetime(2022, 4, 1, 11, 11, 11)
max_date_start = datetime(2022, 4, 2, 11, 11, 11)
min_date_end = datetime(2022, 5, 1, 22, 22, 22)
max_date_end = datetime(2022, 5, 2, 22, 22, 22)

dfs = data_frames(
    index=st.builds(pd.date_range,
                    start=st.datetimes(min_value=min_date_start, max_value=max_date_start).map(boundarize),
                    end=st.datetimes(min_value=min_date_end, max_value=max_date_end).map(boundarize),
                    freq=st.just("15T"),
                    ),
    columns=columns("A B C".split(), dtype=int),
)
dfs.example()
```

The output is the following, note that the integer columns are always zero when they were not in the first example:

```
                     A  B  C
2022-04-01 15:45:00  0  0  0
2022-04-01 16:00:00  0  0  0
2022-04-01 16:15:00  0  0  0
2022-04-01 16:30:00  0  0  0
2022-04-01 16:45:00  0  0  0
...                 .. .. ..
2022-05-01 21:15:00  0  0  0
2022-05-01 21:30:00  0  0  0
2022-05-01 21:45:00  0  0  0
2022-05-01 22:00:00  0  0  0
2022-05-01 22:15:00  0  0  0

[2907 rows x 3 columns]
```

is this expected behavior or am I missing something?

**Edit**:

Sidestepping the approach of "random consecutive subsets" (see my comments below), I also tried with a pre-defined index

```py
from datetime import datetime

from hypothesis.extra.pandas import columns, data_frames
import hypothesis.strategies as st

min_date_start = datetime(2022, 4, 1, 8, 0, 0)

dfs = data_frames(
    index=st.just(pd.date_range(start=min_date_start, periods=10, freq="15T")),
    columns=columns("A B C".split(), dtype=int),
)
dfs.example()
```

which gives all zero columns as well

```
                     A  B  C
2022-04-01 08:00:00  0  0  0
2022-04-01 08:15:00  0  0  0
2022-04-01 08:30:00  0  0  0
2022-04-01 08:45:00  0  0  0
2022-04-01 09:00:00  0  0  0
2022-04-01 09:15:00  0  0  0
2022-04-01 09:30:00  0  0  0
2022-04-01 09:45:00  0  0  0
2022-04-01 10:00:00  0  0  0
2022-04-01 10:15:00  0  0  0
```

**Edit 2**:

I tried to come up with a handmade version of consecutive subsets which should reduce the space of values to leave enough entropy for the column values as per @zac-hatfield-dodds answer, but empirically it still generates mostly all zero column values

```py
from datetime import datetime
import math

import hypothesis.strategies as st
from hypothesis.extra.pandas import columns, data_frames
import pandas as pd

time_start = datetime(2022, 4, 1, 8, 0, 0)
time_stop = datetime(2022, 4, 2, 8, 0, 0)
r = pd.date_range(start=time_start, end=time_stop, freq="15T")

def build_indices(sequence):
    first = 0
    if len(sequence) % 2 == 0:
        mid_ceiling = len(sequence) // 2
        mid_floor = mid_ceiling - 1
    else:
        mid_floor = math.floor(len(sequence) / 2)
        mid_ceiling = mid_floor + 1
    second = len(sequence) - 1
    return first, mid_floor, mid_ceiling, second

first, mid_floor, mid_ceiling, second = build_indices(r)

a = st.integers(min_value=first, max_value=mid_floor)
b = st.integers(min_value=mid_ceiling, max_value=second)

def indexer(sequence, lower, upper):
    return sequence[lower:upper]

dfs = data_frames(
    index=st.builds(lambda lower, upper: indexer(r, lower, upper), lower=a, upper=b),
    columns=columns("A B C".split(), dtype=int),
)
dfs.example()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the latter indexes are *way way larger*, and Hypothesis is running out of entropy to generate column contents.  If you limit the index to at most a few dozen entries, everything should work fine.

We have this soft-cap in order to limit otherwise unbounded recursive structures, so the overall design is working as intended though I acknowledge that in this case it's neither necessary nor desirable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I changed the timeseries bounds to:

`
min_date_start = datetime(2022, 4, 1, 8, 0, 0);
max_date_start = datetime(2022, 4, 1, 8, 30, 0);
min_date_end = datetime(2022, 4, 1, 21, 0, 0);
max_date_end = datetime(2022, 4, 1, 22, 0, 0);
`

but since there are still too many possible timestamps (not aligned to 15 minutes), still the columns are mostly zero or the same non-zero intergers. Maybe it would be better to start out with 15 minutes resolution as mentioned in https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/issues/3220#issuecomment-1016340306 (2nd approach).

Comment: For that "random subsets" approach to work, I would need to sample *consecutive* subsets of the time series. Is there already a Hypothesis strategy to do this?